# I/O ascii codes to foreign characters

Tags: c++, internationalization, ascii

Using `cout << "\n\u00f3\n << endl`, I can print ó with newlines at the Unix command line.  Once I start attempting to read files and print strings containing the characters, I see the literal output instead \n\u00f3\n.

I am not sure if this is because the file read techniques use character arrays or if there is some other nuance I do not know.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
const char *filename ="spanish_project_sample1.txt";
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int c;
    char *data;
    data = " ";
    while ((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        data = appendCharToCharArray(data, c);
    }
    printf("%s", data);
```

Comment: Is this C++ or C?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. "\n\u00f3\n" is a programming language construct for a string value. If you write the value to a text file, the file would contain the bytes for the characters after applying a specific character encoding. (Every reader would have to decode using the same character encoding.) The file contents in this scenario would have nothing to do with the programming language representation (although if properly read into a program under a debugger for a particular language, the debugger _might_ display the string using the language's representation).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the JavaScript solutions to a similar problem (e.g. FromCharCode) and found this code online:
https://ideone.com/Udo3hN

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string FromCharCode ( int num, ... )
{
  va_list arguments;  
  char ch; 
  string s;                 
  va_start ( arguments, num );           
  for ( int x = 0; x < num; x++ )        
   {
         ch = va_arg ( arguments, int ); 
         s = s + ch;
   }
  va_end ( arguments );   
  return s;

}
int main()
{
 cout<<FromCharCode (10,73,78,68,69,83,73,71,78,33,33) ;//<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Specifically, it looks like reading in the characters is the issue because at runtime instead of reading '\n' as value 10 for example, the character array would actually record two ints [92,110].

Using a hardcoded string, the compiler parses the escaped characters as the desired values.

Any suggestions or solutions still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ idiom for reading a file line by line is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string line;
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(argv[1]);

    while(getline(ifs, line))
        cout << line << endl;
}
```

Try that.

Your problem is probably one of interpretation though. If you have "\n\u00f3\n" in a file, that is what it reads and prints. If you have "ó" in the file, which is stored as \u00f3 in UTF-16, you will get what you want. The i/o routines don't do any conversion.

You also need to know if your file is in UTF-8 or UTF-16 so that you can read it properly.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The files are all us-ascii, but it looks like c++ uses utf-8 (executable format possibly dependent on machine's locale settings? Not sure.)  I found this which I think will solve my problem: `char bytes[] = "s\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x87\xaa\xf0\x9f\x87\xb8\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa1";
    printf("%s\n", bytes); `  (convert all the encoded characters to a unicode hex representation)

Comment: I thought about it and also looked at the code.  This is the same problem when I run the code.  I am going to look at some of the special read solutions.  Typing in the hardcoded values compiles and gives the expected output.  Reading the file, I literally print \n\u00f3.  (Either with cout or
        `printf("%s\n", line.c_str());`)